# How to get all task Assigned for Single User in Sharepoint (reporting)

Tags: list, sharepoint, report, task

I have sharepoint 2007 server running on windows server 2003.

This Sharepoint include several sites, each of which represents a project. In each project there is Task list

I need to get a report or list about the tasks that has been assigned for any user in all the projects (sites)

Is there anyway to this?